# Rails 5 Use Bootstrap CDN without gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm starting a Rails 5 application with Bootstrap 3, I'm confused whether to go with gems like [Bootstrap-Sass](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) or use CDN from MaxCDN to rails application.css/js file. I don't plan to modify bootstrap styles, is there any added benefit in using gems other than modifying/mixin.

Using CDN versions should perform better than of gem ?
If I use CDN method there is added benefit of not loading styles/script if user already has it locally in browser ? 
Is there any cons for using CDN links in Rails ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that there are any cons per se but there are subtle differences.

As you already pointed out, there's the advantage that - if it's a "popular" CDN - users may indeed not need to download the file. But that's a big "if".
On the other hand, a CDN can track users to your site because the resource requests contain a `Referer` header.

Personally my suggestion would be to serve all local assets via a CDN of your choice, configured via asset host as described in [section 4.4.1 of the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).
In that setup, you'll have the advantage of speedy asset delivery (no hit against your application server) and full control over the assets delivered.